# How to determine data block encoding method?

Tags: encoding, compression

It is known that the HEX code:
08 45 DB 3C 7E D0 05
means the timestamp range (192 lines)

```
    "2021-11-11 10:24:49 013000us"
    "2021-11-11 10:24:49 113000us"
...
    "2021-11-11 10:25:08 113000us"
```

HEX code:
07 45 DB 3C 7E D0 05
means the timestamp range (192 lines)

```
    "2021-11-11 10:24:49 012999us"
    "2021-11-11 10:24:49 112999us"
...
    "2021-11-11 10:25:08 112999us"
```

HEX code:
00 45 DB 3C 7E D0 05
means the timestamp range (192 lines)

```
    "2021-11-11 10:24:49 012992us"
    "2021-11-11 10:24:49 112992us"
...
    "2021-11-11 10:25:08 112992us"
```

How to determine the encoding method for timestamp range?

Comment: That data is obviously not compressed.

Comment: The hex code has ascii and a block of compressed data

Comment: There is _no_ compressed data in there. Zippo. Nada. Only five byte values in 127..255 are present. Many other byte values are missing. If there were compressed data, that data would have an approximately flat distribution of bytes in 0..255.

Comment: Нow does this code get 192 lines of text?

Comment: I can only guess that it is a binary representation of the data elements, instead of text.

Comment: So, knowing the result, it is impossible to understand how to get it from this code?

Comment: Zeroed some bytes:
00000003D0: D0 05 00 00 00 00 00 A6 │ 8E 3E 01 00 00 73 3D 7E  Р♣     ¦Ћ>☺  s=~
...
0000000540: D0 05 00 00 00 00 00 79 │ 8F 3E 01 00 00 FF 3D 7E  Р♣     yЏ>☺  я=~ result has not changed

Comment: Why did the binary dump just change so dramatically in the question edit?

Comment: To simplify the issue the dump has been shortened

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Unix time multiplied by 1,000,000, and then microseconds added. In little-endian order. That gives the first time of each of your ranges, sort of. For example, for your first one I get 13000 microseconds after 2021-11-11 07:24:49 GMT. So you are showing three hours after GMT, e.g. Moscow time.

The range must be implied.

Comment: That's great! It works